# Implement Static HttpClient in Web App

Tags: c#, azure

Using Vs 2017 community and azure.

I have a web app MVC5, that has this class.

```
public static class SchedulerHttpClient
{
    const string SPNPayload = "resource={0}&client_id={1}&grant_type=client_credentials&client_secret={2}";

    private static HttpClient _Client = new HttpClient();
    public static HttpClient Client{ get { return _Client; } }//TODO: validate

    public static async Task MainAsync()
    {
        string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureTenantId"];
        string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureClientId"];
        string clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureClientSecret"];
        string baseAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseAddress"];

        string token = await AcquireTokenBySPN(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret).ConfigureAwait(false);

        _Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token); //TODO ssmith: const or localization
        _Client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
    }

    private static async Task<string> AcquireTokenBySPN(string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret)
    {
        var payload = String.Format(SPNPayload,
                                    WebUtility.UrlEncode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ARMResource"]),
                                    WebUtility.UrlEncode(clientId),
                                    WebUtility.UrlEncode(clientSecret));

        var body = await HttpPost(tenantId, payload).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return body.access_token;
    }

    private static async Task<dynamic> HttpPost(string tenantId, string payload)
    {
        var address = String.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TokenEndpoint"], tenantId);
        var content = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        using (var response = await _Client.PostAsync(address, content).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Status:  {0}", response.StatusCode);
                Console.WriteLine("Content: {0}", await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
            }

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<dynamic>().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

This class is meant to spin up a Httpclient, contact azure get a token, and set the client with it, this way i can re-use with authorization.

Issue is when and how to call the class, currently I have tried the Global.asx, the HomeController Constructor method and the Index method.

```
public HomeController()
    {
        //Init();
    }

    public async void Init()
    {
        await SchedulerHttpClient.MainAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        Init();
        try
        {
            await MakeARMRequests().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.GetBaseException().Message);
        }

        return View();
    }
```

The error i get is

> [InvalidOperationException: An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.]

Is my static class implemented correctly? If so, how would i instantiate the client and then re-use across my app?

**UPDATE @Stephen Cleary:**

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        await SchedulerHttpClient.ClientTask.ConfigureAwait(false);
        try
        {
            await MakeARMRequests().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.GetBaseException().Message);
        }

        return View();
    }

    static async Task MakeARMRequests()
    {
        const string ResourceGroup = "fakegrp";

        // Create the resource group

        // List the Web Apps and their host names
        var client = await SchedulerHttpClient.ClientTask;
        var response = await client.GetAsync(
            $"/subscriptions/{Subscription}/resourceGroups/{ResourceGroup}/providers/Microsoft.Web/sites?api-version=2015-08-01");

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        var json = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<dynamic>().ConfigureAwait(false);
        foreach (var app in json.value)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(app.name);
            foreach (var hostname in app.properties.enabledHostNames)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("  " + hostname);
            }
        }
}
```

Here is the refactored class as per suggestion.

```
public static class SchedulerHttpClient
{
    const string SPNPayload = "resource={0}&client_id={1}&grant_type=client_credentials&client_secret={2}";

    private static Lazy<Task<HttpClient>> _Client = new Lazy<Task<HttpClient>>(async () =>
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        await MainAsync(client).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return client;
    });

    public static Task<HttpClient> ClientTask => _Client.Value;

    private static async Task MainAsync(HttpClient client)
    {
        string tenantId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureTenantId"];
        string clientId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureClientId"];
        string clientSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureClientSecret"];
        string baseAddress = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseAddress"];

        string token = await AcquireTokenBySPN(client, tenantId, clientId, clientSecret).ConfigureAwait(false);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + token); //TODO ssmith: const or localization
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);
    }

    private static async Task<string> AcquireTokenBySPN(HttpClient client, string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret)
    {
        var payload = String.Format(SPNPayload,
                                    WebUtility.UrlEncode(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ARMResource"]),
                                    WebUtility.UrlEncode(clientId),
                                    WebUtility.UrlEncode(clientSecret));

        var body = await HttpPost(client, tenantId, payload).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return body.access_token;
    }

    private static async Task<dynamic> HttpPost(HttpClient client, string tenantId, string payload)
    {
        var address = String.Format(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["TokenEndpoint"], tenantId);
        var content = new StringContent(payload, Encoding.UTF8, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        using (var response = await client.PostAsync(address, content).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Status:  {0}", response.StatusCode);
                Console.WriteLine("Content: {0}", await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));
            }

            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            return await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<dynamic>().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the need to use a static class here? The result is that your `HttpClient` could be shared between multiple threads at the same time.

Comment: @JLRishe Im trying to re-use the httpclient i set with authorization throughout the lifetime of my app. as suggested in other forums

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is due to `async void`. As noted in my [intro to `async` on ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx) article:

> When an asynchronous handler completes the request, but ASP.NET detects asynchronous work that hasn’t completed, you get an Invalid­OperationException with the message, “An asynchronous module or handler completed while an asynchronous operation was still pending.” This is usually due to asynchronous code calling an async void method...

Also see my [article on `async` best practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) for other reasons to avoid `async void`.

In your case, you have a singleton resource that requires initialization, and that initialization must be asynchronous. You only want to start the initialization once, and all callers should share the initialization result, so a `Lazy<T>` seems appropriate. Since the initialization is asynchronous, it can be represented by a `Task`. Hence, a `Lazy<Task>`:

```
public static class SchedulerHttpClient
{
  ... // Same as above, but making MainAsync private.
  public static readonly Lazy<Task> Initialize = new Lazy<Task>(() => MainAsync());
}
```

Usage:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
  await SchedulerHttpClient.Initialize.Value.ConfigureAwait(false);
  try
  {
    await MakeARMRequests().ConfigureAwait(false);
  }
  catch (Exception e)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(e.GetBaseException().Message);
  }

  return View();
}
```

This will be enough to get your code working, but I would go a step further and refactor `SchedulerHttpClient` so that it only exposes the `HttpClient` after it has been initialized:

```
public static class SchedulerHttpClient
{
  private static Lazy<Task<HttpClient>> _Client = new Lazy<Task<HttpClient>>(async () =>
  {
    var client = new HttpClient();
    await MainAsync(client).ConfigureAwait(false);
    return client;
  });
  public static Task<HttpClient> ClientTask => _Client.Value;

  private static async Task MainAsync(HttpClient client) { ... }
  private static async Task<string> AcquireTokenBySPN(HttpClient client, string tenantId, string clientId, string clientSecret) { ... }
  private static async Task<dynamic> HttpPost(HttpClient client, string tenantId, string payload) { ... }
}
```

This forces your `MakeARMRequests` to `await` on `SchedulerHttpClient.ClientTask` instead of accessing the `HttpClient` directly, so you don't have to remember to do it in all your controller methods.

As a final note, you may want to "reset" the `Lazy<T>` if the initialization actually fails. That would complicate this homegrown solution sufficiently that I would recommend using [my `AsyncLazy<T>` type](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx/blob/master/src/Nito.AsyncEx.Coordination/AsyncLazy.cs) instead ([available on NuGet](https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx.Coordination)).

Comment: before i was using var response = await SchedulerHttpClient.ClientTask.GetAsync(...  But now my static class only exposes the client as a task, sounds silly but how do i utilize the client?
Ive called await SchedulerHttpClient.ClientTask.ConfigureAwait(false); inside the index call.

Comment: @lemunk: `var client = await SchedulerHttpClient.ClientTask; var response = await client.GetAsync(...);`. If you want it all on one line, you'd need to use parenthesis: `var response = await (await SchedulerHttpClient.ClientTask).GetAsync(...);`

Comment: ok so i removed my call in my index and now set var client = await SchedulerHttpClient.ClientTask;  when i run im hit with an Error: This instance has already started one or more requests. Properties can only be modified before sending the first request.

Comment: Ill update my question to show you how my controller looks

Comment: @lemunk: That error shouldn't happen if you're using `Lazy<T>`.

Comment: No idea, anything to do with IIS express and vs 2017? (random thoughts).

Comment: @lemunk: No. It's more likely a missing `await` somewhere.

Comment: Checked the code no missing awaits at all, the SchedulerHttpClient class is exactly like your's and my controller is updated in my question.Async debugging is always a pain, but stepping through the error occurs here "client.BaseAddress = new Uri(baseAddress);" on the schedulerhttpclient

Comment: Seems when i move the base address line into the _Client property it works fine, ssems you cant set other propertys of http client after going into another method?  is this the case? or fluke i solved it?

Comment: @lemunk: Ah, yes. The `BaseAddress` (and all other properties) must be set before `AcquireTokenBySPN` is called, because that uses the same client to make an actual call.

Comment: Also, If i wanted to use this in another class how could i use it in my constructor?  i cant await inside a constructor, i just want to set a private property to my static httpclient so i can use it anywhere in my class. without having to create a new var client = await ShcedulerHttpClient.ClientTask;

Comment: @lemunk: I discuss [async constructors](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/01/async-oop-2-constructors.html) on my blog. If you have further questions, I recommend you ask another question.